# Oracle Identity Manager Create Request Viewer Role

Tags: oracle, identity

I am working with Oracle Identity Manager. I would like to create a new role that allows a user to view the requests other users have made, without modifying those requests.

My first attempt was to login as an administrator, go to manage, administrative roles, create new role.  I filled in the details and under capabilities added "User - View Requests".  I assigned a test user to this role.  When I login as the test user though, I can only view the requests of that user, not other users' requests as intended.  The drop down for requests did not include the "All" or "For User" option.

After that I looked through the Oracle Fusion Middleware User's Guide for Oracle Identity Manager, but all I could find was a reference saying to view other users' requests you need one of a couple different administrator roles.  I do not want to grant these admin roles as they provide too many permissions.

Is it possible to create a new role that allows a user to view other users' requests without editing them? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

In OIM there are few capabilities which didn't worked(its bug) if you given it through OIM GUI, **User - View Requests** capability is one of them. Try same capability by giving using api then it should work.

Admin API URL:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMJAV/oracle/iam/platformservice/api/AdminRoleService.html